# Approved Excel addin missing from Mac store

Tags: office-js, office-store

[Our Excel add-in](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA200000046) was approved by Microsoft several months ago, and it shows as expected in the Windows and Web versions of Excel. However, we cannot get it to show on ANY Mac version of Excel.

To reproduce:

1. Within Excel for Mac, go to the Insert ribbon tab and select `Get Add-ins`. The store dialog pops up.
2. Search for "MyEducator". The dreaded "There are no add-ins matching these criteria" shows up.
3. If you try the same search on Excel for Windows, the add-in shows up just fine.

We have been working with Microsoft support for two weeks (paid $500 for dedicated support), and they cannot figure out why it doesn't show up. We have been through several levels of support. They say our manifest requirements are correct, but they also don't see the add-in. Today, they finally just asked us to try here :).

The manifest file has the following requirements set:

```
<Hosts>
  <Host Name="Workbook" />
</Hosts>
<Requirements>
  <Sets>
    <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.8"/>
  </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

The [Microsoft platform availability doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability) shows that Office 365 Mac supports `ExcelApi 1.8`. (for completeness, we aren't using "Mac version 16 one-time purchase", which does not support 1.8.)

When we open the "About Excel" dialog, we see the following:

```
                 Microsoft Excel for Mac

                 Version 16.30 (19101301)
               Product ID: 02954-063-109715
             License: Office 365 Subscription

         (c) 2019 Microsoft. All Rights Reserved.
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit Later**

Just to finish this out for any who read about it in the future, Microsoft worked with us offline to make this work. It was some issue in their store. Keyur was amazing.

Comment: Hi! Sorry you're hitting this issue, we're looking into it for you and will respond back as soon as we can respond and investigate. Will try to provide an update within 24-48 hours. thanks.

Comment: Thank you for looking at it, Keyur!

Comment: @Keyur we are facing the same issue with our Outlook add-in, any chance we could get this fixed? https://appsource.microsoft.com/de-de/product/office/WA104381095?tab=Overview

Comment: Hi @mnkypete — sorry for your issue as well, the team is following up to see what is occurring here. We were able to confirm the issue. Will let you know when addressed.

Comment: Hey @KeyurPatel-MSFT, we are now also experiencing the same issue. Our Excel add-in has been published and passed certification for two weeks now and it still does not come up on the Office store in Excel - but we can find it on AppSource here: can https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-au/product/office/WA200002094?tab=Overview

Comment: Hey @kkliebersbach - what version of Mac / office are you reproing this against? Can you also specify if you have any requirement sets on the manifest?

Comment: Hi @KeyurPatel-MSFT - we have the Requirement set ExcelApi MinVersion=1.11. I cannot find it in Excel Windows (Build 2009) and Excel Online, both of which satisfy the requirement..

Comment: Thanks, will check with team today

Comment: @KeyurPatel-MSFT how did the team go with the issue? We are still struggling to find it on the Office store, but can find it on AppSource...